# AdMob request is very slow (over 10 seconds)

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, iad

As soon as my app loads I request an ad using this code in viewDidLoad:

```
self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 421, 320, 50)];
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3508264504594125/9347203891";
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
self.bannerView.delegate = self;

[self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

On average it takes 5 seconds from the time I request the ad until adViewDidReceiveAd is called and the ad is displayed.

When the user taps on a button the next view controller is displayed, and an ad is called using the same code. However, this time it takes an average of 11-12 seconds to display the ad. By this time, the user will most likely have moved on without seeing the ad.

Is there any reason why this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If you have all your `UIViewController` embeded in `UINavigationController` you should add a ad banner to `UINavigationController` parent view controller and make navigation controller smaller (navigation controller and banner should be visible when `GADRequest` finished). This way ad will be independent from a current root view controller and in addtion you can fully control when show or hide your ad.